# Can a saddle point corresponding to black hole horizon act as a source of chaos?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, string-theory, ads-cft, chaos-theory

I was going through [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.06756) paper where on **page 5** they argue that in the given Poincare section:

> Most of the orbits form regular tori, while we can also see that some tori near the saddle point of the potential collapses to become scattered plots. This saddle point corresponds to the black hole horizon, hence we confirmed that a black hole horizon works as a source of chaos.

I am a bit confused by this statement. Any detailed explanation would be truly beneficial!